# What variable name do you use for file descriptors?

Tags: python, file, naming-conventions, explicit, variable-names

A pretty silly trivial question.  The canonical example is `f = open('filename')`, but

- `f` is not very descriptive.  After not looking at code in a while,
  you can forget whether it means
  "file" or "function f(x)" or "fourier
  transform results" or something else.  EIBTI.
- In Python, `file` is already taken by a function.

What else do you use?

Comment: `file()` was deprecated in 2.x then flat out removed in 3.x, so IMHO it's fair game

Comment: @NickT Good.  I'm always confused whether to use `file` or `open`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 data_file
 settings_file
 results_file
 .... etc
```

Comment: "Method Names and Instance Variables - Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability." http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @endolith: You should use my suggestion for Python code. Camel case is Java style.

Comment: As I said, "with" doesn't work for me, and "f" is too short and non-descript (which was the whole point of this question).  I wish this answer were python style, but it's still the best of the bunch.

Answer (score 6):

You can append it to the beginning, Hungarian-like "file_fft".

However, I would try to close file descriptors as soon as possible, and I recommend using the with statement like this so you don't have to worry about closing it, and it makes it easier to not lose track of it.

```
with open("x.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    do something with data
```

Comment: "with" is a great!  It has definitely cleaned my code up considerable.  You can use it in 2.5 "from __future__ import with_statement"

Comment: The object I'm using to open the file does not work with with statements.  "object has no attribute '__exit__'"

Comment: @endolith: Then use [`contextlib.closing`](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing).

Answer (score 4):

I'm happy to use `f` (for either a function OR a file;-) if that identifier's scope is constrained to a pretty small compass (such as `with open('zap') as f:` would normally portend, say). In general, identifiers with large lexical scopes should be longer and more explicit, ones with lexically small/short scopes/lifespans can be shorter and less explicit, and this applies to open file object just about as much as to any other kind of object!-)

Answer (score 3):

Generally if the scope of a file object is only a few lines, `f` is perfectly readable - the variable name for the filename in the open call is probably descriptive enough. otherwise `something_file` is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

generally I'll use "fp" for a short-lifetime file pointer.

for a longer-lived descriptor, I'll be more descriptive.  "fpDebugLog", for example.

Answer (score 0):

I rather use one of: `f, fp, fd`.

Sometimes `inf` / `outf` for input and output file.